# Как нарисовать линию в андроид?

Tags: android

У меня есть несколько  TextView, после каждого из них нужно нарисовать черную линию горизонтальную?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Горизонтальная линия:

```
       <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorLine"
        android:layout_height="1sp"/>
```

Вертикальная линия:

```
       <View
        android:layout_width="1sp"
        android:background="@color/colorLine"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: Я всегда стараюсь избегать лишнего кода, поэтому такой подход считаю неправильным. Но если это используется только один раз, то ничего страшного. А если это адаптер с листом товаров, и если мы выводим ~1к за раз, то лишнему view тут не место.

Comment: С вами согласен,но если у вас 1к элементов, вы обязаны организовать пагинацию списка.

Comment: Можно и без пагинации же кидать в тот же List. А если и с ней, то смысл тот же, вьюх в памяти одинаковое количество. Или мы друг друга не поняли)

Answer (score 1):

**Android линия используя drawable ресурсы:**

*../drawable/line.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-1dp" android:right="-1dp" android:left="-1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
    <!--здесь android:bottom="1dp" толщина линии
        вы можете манипулировать этими параметрами и также сделать вертикальную линию-->
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#5580CBC4"/><!--толщина и цвет линии-->
        <!--<solid android:color="#5580CBC4"/>--><!--если нужен фон для TextView-->
        <!--<corners android:radius="3dp"/>--><!--если нужен радиус-->
    </shape>
</item>
```

**Использование:**

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/line"
    ...
/>
```